# How to properly scale/rotate images in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, pyqtgraph

I have implemented `pyqtgraph` inside `QGraphicsView` in PyQt5. When I display the image the following way, it is stretched out and expands in the same aspect ratio as the screen. How do I fix this?

```
image = pg.ImageItem(asarray(Image.open('pic.png')) )      
self.graphicsView.addItem(image)
image.rotate(270)
```

EDIT: found out how to rotate image, so I updated question with the solution. Now I am just trying to scale it properly.

Answer (score 6):

You probably want something like:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray

app = pg.mkQApp()

# Set up a window with ViewBox inside
gv = pg.GraphicsView()
vb = pg.ViewBox()
gv.setCentralItem(vb)
gv.show()

# configure view for images
vb.setAspectLocked()
vb.invertY()

# display image
img_data = asarray(Image.open('/home/luke/tmp/graph.png'))
image = pg.ImageItem(img_data, axisOrder='row-major')
vb.addItem(image)
```

The important pieces here that set the image scaling/orientation are:

- using `ImageItem(axisOrder='row-major')` because image files are stored in row-major order
- `vb.invertY()` because image files have the +y axis pointing downward
- and `vb.setAspectLocked()` to keep the pixels square

Answer (score 3):

I used `np.rot90()` instead, it's much faster and cythonable

```py
image = pg.ImageItem(np.rot90(np.asarray(Image.open('pic.png'))))
```